# picture taken from external bluetooth connected camera -> save to smartphone camera folder

Tags: android, camera

i am using macrodroid and tasker to automate multiple triggers/actions in an android smartphone. I have managed to use this as a trigger for example: a specific android intent is received and then a photo is taken (even when the smartphone is locked) and the photo is sent as an attcachment via email.

I want to do exactly the same with an **external mini camera**. I am trying to find an external mini camera that can be connected via bluetooth with my android smartphone and when a trigger like an intent is received (for example in macrodroid), the external camera will take a picture and will save it IN my smartphone's camera folder. I do not want wires, only wireless connection. Also, preferably, the external camera, should be in wait mode, so only when the triggers happens, it will take the picure.

I have already found some cameras that save the photos they take inside THEIR app, for example an external camera will have an app that you can control the camera. But, ideally, this would be the best for my situation: control the external camera NOT from its own external-camera-app but from the native android camera app and save the photo to the Camera Folder.

Thank you in advance for your time and advices

Comment: Any reason you cant just use the phone.